# indexing using to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')) function

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, timestamp, to-char

I have the following in my SQL where clause. This is running against an Oracle database. The timestamp field is defined in the database as a timestimp field.
my select query is :

```
create index ind_timestamp on sms_in(to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD'));

select * from sms_in where to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')in '2018-08-01';
```

but when I'm tring to execut the query the database acces is full. That means the indexing doesn't work.

Comment: Wondering why an `IN` clause and not `=` in the query

Comment: How does the plan change if you change `in` to `=`? Also, how many rows are in your table, and how many of those rows have `TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ` equal to `2018-08-01`? Also, when was the last time you gathered statistics on this table? Use `SELECT LAST_ANALYZED FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SMS_IN'` to find out.

Comment: also, it's better to run dbms_stats.gather_table_stats() on sms_in table to update optimizer calculations.

Comment: why are you using function based index, add an index on timestamp column and convert  your string to timestamp in the where clause

Comment: The query result is correct the issue is with the index it doesn't work.

Comment: also I'm using the indexing because  the table contains more than 100K records.
While fetching the records, the cpu usage goes to 100%.

Comment: i don't say you shouldn't use an index. you shoul use a normal index on column and not an function based index

Comment: @hotfix - that mechanism won't quite work without some more effort on the query, the to_char is truncating the timestamp, removing the time element. If he converts a date to timestamp, it will be midnight by default, and not match without the extra logic / effort (this assumes his timestamps are not being set as pure dates)

Comment: @Andrew he could use  `between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59` and that should use an index

Comment: @Andrew that's true I'm using the timestamp with diffrent format.

Comment: @hotfix - agreed, that is the extra query work which I think needs to be spelt out if you write up your comment in an answer.

Comment: @hotfix that mechanism doesn't work.

Comment: How many different dates are in the table? (`select count(distinct trunc(timestamp)) from sms_in`) The DBMS will only use the index when it expects only a small part of the table to match the criteria. And an `IN` clause makes it much less likely that an index be used. This is no problem; a full table scan, even for millions of rows, can still be faster than an index access. And that 100% CPU usage is also not bad per se.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the table have  215  different dates.

Comment: @DachCh i don't see a reason why? you should tell me why it doesn't work.

Comment: @hotfix the table acces is full it cost 4014 like I'm not using an index.

Comment: @DachCh add your execution plan

Comment: I would rather create an index on `TRUNC(timestamp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are always looking for the data for a particular day, then my suggestion would be  as follow

you add an in normal index on `timestamp` column

```
create index ind_timestamp on sms_in(timestamp);
```

your select could Looks like

```
select * 
  from sms_in 
 where timestamp between to_date('2018-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                     and to_date('2018-08-01 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

or you can do it like

```
select * 
  from sms_in 
 where timestamp >= to_date('2018-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  and timestamp  <= to_date('2018-08-01 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

EDIT:

This answer is basically correct, but the logic should be:

```
select * 
 from sms_in 
 where timestamp >= date '2018-08-01' and
       timestamp < date '2018-08-02 ;
```

Comment: This will not get any timestamps between `23:59:59.999000001` and `23:59:59.999999999` you would be better using `WHERE timestamp >= TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP '2018-01-02 00:00:00'.

Comment: you are right, but first we should know how the data in his table looks like. maybe he just save FF3

Comment: The timestamp column type is date,it look like 'YYYY-MM-DD'. But I'm using other query where I want only 'YYYY-MM' or 'YYYY' or 'MM' etc. It depends of what I'm fetching.

Comment: we don't know about another cases you do, if you Need it too, you have to edit your question and add all cases you want to be handled

Comment: This answer is correct but I don't know how to obtain the next day ('2018-08-02') .

Comment: `date '2018-08-01' +1`